# Tunnel ssh over http with custom headers

Tags: http, vpn, ssh, proxy, tunneling

I'm trying to set up [corkscrew](https://github.com/bryanpkc/corkscrew) to make an SSH tunnel over HTTP, but I need to add custom headers after the "CONNECT" statement and before the ssh tunnel.

Does corkscrew support it? If yes, how can I enable it?

Comment: According to [the code](https://github.com/bryanpkc/corkscrew/blob/master/corkscrew.c#L219) it does not support it. But, you might change the source code to add your own headers - it does not look that hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Since [corkscrew](https://github.com/bryanpkc/corkscrew) doesn't support HTTP custom headers, i found out another tool which does it.

It's called [ProxyTunnel](https://github.com/proxytunnel/proxytunnel) and has a lot of support for custom data inside the HTTP payload.